# Actions on spaces with measured walls

Tags: gr.group-theory, examples, geometric-group-theory

In geometric group theory, the question of whether or not a group acts nicely on a CAT(0) cube complex, or equivalently on a median graph, is of interest. The same question for actions on spaces with measured walls, or equivalently on median spaces, turns out to be interesting too because of its links with Kazhdan's property (T) and Haagerup property. However, as far as I know, this generalization seems to be only of theoritical interest, I don't know any (discrete) group which has been studied thanks to an action on a median space rather than a median graph. Hence my question:

> Do you know examples of (discrete) groups which act naturally on a median space and not on a CAT(0) cube complex?

Comment: See example 6.4 of this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.5982

Comment: Groups acting on $\mathbb{R}$-trees could be a good special case to consider.